# How to active user-attribute in GLSL code? optimize(off) not work

Tags: optimization, attributes, glsl

vertex shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 MCVertex;
in float pointvar;

uniform mat4 MVMatrix;
uniform mat4 MPMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = MPMatrix * MVMatrix * vec4(MCVertex, 1.0);
}
```

i need 'pointvar' attribute

but when i call :

```
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES, &numAttributes);

numAttribute = 1;
```

there are 2 attribute in my code, numAttribute must be 2.

and if i do it like this, i can active this attribute:

```
gl_Position = MPMatrix * MVMatrix * vec4(MCVertex + vec3(pointvar), 1.0);
```

then `numAttributes = 2`, is there any other ways to active this attribute?
i have try to `#pragma optimize(off)`, but not work.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want to activate an attribute you don't use anyway. And if you use it, it is activated anyway. So where's the problem?

Comment: i can active this var if it has some connection with gl_Position,that's what i mean.

Comment: past this var from vert to frag not actvie this var. i have try to " in float point_angle " and " out mat2 uv_rotate " to fragment search rotate texture, but i cant find "point_angle" when get attribute location. Seems some graphic card work, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that GLSL will "erase/forget" any uniform / attribute not used in it's code.

All the info [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Object).

EDIT:

> Like uniforms, attributes can be active or inactive. Attributes that
>   are unused are inactive; they do not have a binding.

Comment: i know, that's why i use gl_Position = MPMatrix * MVMatrix * vec4(MCVertex + vec3(pointvar), 1.0); to active my attribute, but i don't like this way, so i ask another.

Comment: @user1069041: There is no other way. The point of active attributes is to allow the compiler the ability to get rid of stuff you don't use. You can use all the `#pragma`s you want, but the compiler still has the freedom to get rid of any attribute it sees go unused. In short, you *must* make allowances in your code for this possibility.

Comment: that's bad, i just need point index in my code, but i found gl_VertexID not work in some graphic cards, so i want to past an attribute index array to my shader..